# Can I make local (only) git repository without Github or similar? Is that what "Initialize Repository" does?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I want to do git-based version control, but with all my (committed or otherwise) files only on my local drive, without syncing or committing or communicating in any way to/with GitHub's or anyone else's servers anywhere.

[VSCode's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_initialize-a-repository) describes two options: "Initialize Repository" or "Publish to GitHub".

So is a repository something that must be on GitHub, or does "Initialize Repository" allow me to create a repository on my local machine, with all version control managed and stored on my local drive, without anything ever being uploaded to a GitHub account?

If it's possible, are there any special steps I need to take or does the "Initialize Repository" option mean it's all local intrinsically (because it's *the alternative to* "Publish..."?)

Comment: In git the "local only" case *is* the default and connecting a newly initialized repo to a remote is a second step. Many tools conflate the two, simply because it is so frequent to do both.

Comment: You could also read the official git documentation: https://git-scm.com/doc

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: just type `git init` in the workspace folder and off you go, no need to use github

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is something you could simply try ;-)

Initialize Repository will create a new local repository.

Unless you define a remote repository and push your commits nothing will leave your computer. Usually it is a good idea to use a remote repository so you can synchronize your code with other developers, other workstations and have a backup copy of your codebase.

> So is a repository something that must be on GitHub

No a respository is just a bunch of extra files, added to your project.
The local git repository is in a hidden folder named .git which is placed in the root folder of your project (where you created the git repository).

Comment: And to expand on the "you could simply try": people are too afraid to try stuff like that. But especially for Github and co it's fairly easy: if nothing asks you to connect/authenticate/... to any such service, then chances are the tool doesn't upload anything. And if it *does* unexpectedly ask you for credentials, then simply abort the process, as nothing could be uploaded at that point. This kind of advice applies to so many things ...